# If $\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(a,c)=1$ then $\gcd(a,bc)=1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I need help in this. If $a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(a,c)=1$ then $\gcd(a,bc)=1$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$gcd(a,b) = 1$ gives: $am + bn = 1$ for some integers $m, n$. Similarly: $ap + cq = 1$ for some integers $p, q$. So: $(am + bn)(ap + cp) = 1$, and expand: $a^2mp + acmp + abnp + bcnp = 1$ and regroup: $a(amp + cmp + bnp) + bc(np) = 1$, proving $gcd(a, bc) = 1$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** $\ $ Notice $\ \color{#0a0}{(a,b)(a,c)} = (aa,ab,ac,bc) = (a\color{#c00}{(a,b,c)},bc)\ $ by gcd laws.

Yours is special case $\,\color{#0a0}{(a,b)} = 1 = \color{#0a0}{(a,c)},\,$ hence $\,\color{#c00}{(a,b,c)}=1.$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose to the contrary that $\gcd(a,bc)\gt 1$. Then there is a **prime** $p$ that divides $a$ and $bc$. But then $p$ divides $b$ or $p$ divides $c$.

That's impossible, since if $p$ divides $b$, then $\gcd(a,b)\gt 1$, contradicting the hypothesis that $\gcd(a,b)=1$. We obtain a similar contradiction if we suppose that $p$ divides $c$.